# ASP.NET MVC 3 OutputCache Routing : 2 routes for 1 action make 2 cached pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, outputcache

"The outputcache is caching 2 pages (there's 2 URLs) for just 1 same action"
WHY ??
I tought outputcache was looking for routedata values..., no?

So, 
On my website, i have 2 URLs for the Home page :

"http://www.domain.com/"

and

"http://www.domain.com/search/mysearchpage.htm"

Here are the routes :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "nameofmyroute",
                "search/mysearchpage.htm",
                new { controller = "Search", action = "do", id = "" },
                new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }
            );

routes.MapRoute("Default",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",    
                new { controller = "Search", action = "do", id = "" },
                new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }
            );
```

Here is my caching config:

```
<add name="defaultcache"
duration="3600"
enabled="true" 
location="ServerAndClient" />
```

When i ask for "/" url =>my action is firing and the all the action is done.
When i re-ask for "/" => my action is not fired => cool it's working ! it's taken from the cache.

But:
When i ask for "/search/mysearchpage.htm" => my action is also fired !
I don't understand why...

PS:There's no parameter on my Action.

Do you have an explanation for that ?
Thanks a lot ! :)

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Outputcache provider is based on Url and not your routing.

Comment: ok thks, but is that the normal processing of the default ouputcache provider ?

Comment: Yes, MVC output caching is the same that webform based on URL's (by default). However, you can reimplement provider which you can replace the url key by the "restful path" [Demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433822/net-4-0-implementing-outputcacheprovider)